# use pyspark row as dataframe header

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark data frame with just 2 records. Out of these 2 records, I have to extract latest record and use that as the header for another dataframe

ex:

```
df1
col_1 col_2 col_2
em_name mg_name 2020-06-09
em_name mgr_name 2020-07-09
```

from this I have to extract em_name,mgr_name as list and use this as the header for another dataframe. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by **" I have to extract em_name, mgr_name as list "** ? What's your use case , can you put a detailed description?

Answer (score 0):

Just collect the row you want

```py
row = df.orderBy(F.desc('col3')).first()
col_0 = row['Prop_0']
col_1 = row['Prop_1']
col_2 = row['Prop_2']
```

Comment: the result is coming in this format - Row(Prop_0='em_name ', Prop_1='mgr_name ') I just need the row values in a list...

Comment: K, check the updated answer